# Как авторизовать пользователя через HH API?

Tags: python, aiogram, api

Коллеги подскажите с такой проблемой. После авторизации пользователя кидает на указанный адрес {redirect_uri}?code={authorization_code} и в нем лежит authorization_code, так вот, каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы редирект был на свой сервер и данные от туда вытаскивались и отправлялись, допустим в телеграмм-бот. Хотя бы концептуально как это реализовать используя python? Мое видение такое, надо поднять какой-нибудь сервер, допустим, FastAPI, но вот вообще не понимаю как забирать данные от туда. Может надо использовать работу с бд, ну к примеру, идет гет запрос на этот адрес и данные кода заносятся в бд, но тут стоит другой вопрос, как понять, что данный код принадлежит конкретному пользователю? В общем, мое видение скорее всего ошибочное, буду рад, если вы мне подскажите с этим вопросом!